# String To timestamp conversion is giving me null in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to convert string to timestamp through OTB azure data factory expression builder. It is fetching value as null as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]
I know it is a very basic query but I am stuck here for some time. After the string value is converted to timestamp I need to perform a timestamp comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Found solution. I need to add a backslash escape character for literal 'T'
'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm'